# ways to transpose the Rows into Columns in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

Actually i got requirement like i have to transpose the Row data into Column for Dynamically.

Material materiral_type value
20          x1           10
20          x2           20
20          x3           70
20          x4           80
30          x1           10
30          x5           20

Result required in SAP HANA :
material x1    x2  x3  x4  x5 ...etc.,
20       10    20  70  80  0
30       10    0   0    0  20

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in command (like PIVOT/UNPIVOT) in SAP HANA (up to SPS12). 
You can create your own dynamic transformations either in SQLSCript or in the information view editor. 
This topic has been covered extensibly in the SAP Community Network. Just search there: https://onedx.find.sap.com/s#t=hana%20pivot&n=1&p=default&repo=srh